# buildozer подключение файлов

Tags: python, json, kivy, buildozer

Пытаюсь скомпилировать через `buildozer apk` приложение на андроид. Использую `Python` + `Kivy` + пакеты от google и `oauth`.

Исполняемый фаил `main.py` запрашивает информацию из `json` файла, который находится с ним в одной папке.

Вопрос в следующем. При компиляции , процесс сборки `apk` воздействует только с `main.py`, а с `json` файлом нет. Думаю проблема в этом, так как приложение не запускается и при компиляции ошибок нет. Как подключить `json` отдельный файл, чтобы `buidozer` его тоже компилировал вместе с `main.py`.

Comment: Попытка запуска приложения так и не получилась, нашел способ запускать apk с sdcard с целью просмотра логов последнего запуска приложения. Ничего в логи почему то не записывается.

Comment: Ну тут явно проблема не в модуле так как при запуске на pc все отлично запускается, скорее всего необходимо как то в spec файле прописать json файл или что то типо того. Видимо он его не видит. Попробую сегодня в main.py ипортировать json и прописать его там же не отдельным файлом.  Хоть я и нашел способ запускать фаил без компиляции на андроиде хочется полноценное приложение сделать.